# Using EntityFramework.HierarchyId in CodeFirst approach, The Type hierarchyid is not qualified with a namespace or alias

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, hierarchy

I'm starting new project and I'd like to use HierarchyID in my DB model and CodeFirst approach. So I added EntityFramework.HierarchyId using nuget.

But when I run Update-Database, I receive this exception:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(0,0) : error 0040: The Type hierarchyid is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only primitive types can be used without qualification.
```

This is how my table looks like:

```
public class Activity
{
    [Key]
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }

    public HierarchyId ActivityPath { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I know that I had to miss samething easy, but I'm not able to find useful sample on Google. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a reason of this issue.
Because the whole solution is new, it was using ./express database (I don't know why it chose exactly this instance... maybe it's default). And even if I have installed MS SQL 2012, instance of ./express is SQL2005 -> no hierarchyId support. When I specified connection string explicitly to newer version, problem solved.

I'll keep this post to help others... Don't forget to vote up if you are one of them.

Comment: I Had a similar issue - and the reason was - a spelling mistake in TYPE of EDMX